# How to install CPLEX on Julia 1.0?

Tags: julia, cplex

I am using macOS and JuliaPro v1.0.1.1. I have installed CPLEX from IBM and added it to the path. Next, I run

```
(JuliaPro_v1.0.1.1) pkg> add CPLEX
```

but this gives me

```
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * CPLEX (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

When I run

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get

```
/Applications/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/bin/x86-64_osx:
```

I do not know what I am missing here...

Comment: I ran the command without the error...could this be a setup or other networking problem between your machine and the CPLEX.jl repository?

Comment: How can I find out if this is a networking problem?

Comment: Can you view https://github.com/JuliaOpt/CPLEX.jl in a browser on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the colon (:) at the end of LD_LIBRARY_PATH (wherever you define it).